# What do we call for non machine learning approaches?

Tags: machine-learning, sensors

I am doing a research on stroke classifications using machine learning which called *"Machine Learning Approach"*. Also there are systems that have used embedded sensors to the system and classify the stokes directly by using depth data (by gyroscope/sensor modules) other than using machine learning approach. Can I know, what does that method call ?

Comment: It belongs to another SE site. More to AI.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single answer to this question. It's all about algorithms and their types.
There are a variety of machine learning and non-machine learning based algorithms, some of which are -

- Simple recursive algorithms
- Rule-based algorithms <---- *This is probably what you ask for in your* question
- Backtracking algorithms
- Divide and conquer algorithms
- Dynamic programming algorithms
- Greedy algorithms
- Branch and bound algorithms
- Brute force algorithms
- Randomized algorithms
- Machine learning algorithms

Different texts will have different categorizations.

Another way of looking at the whole thing is the black box approach.

[image]

First are optimization approaches where you know the model and output but don't know the input.

[image]

Second, are simulation approaches where you know the model and the input, but don't know the output.

[image]

Lastly, are the mathematical modeling approaches, where you know the inputs and the outputs but don't know the model.

[image]

Machine learning is a subclass of this class of approaches and is set up such that you reframe the problem as an optimization approach. Here you say that you know the inputs which is a combination of `[X, y, Model(theta)]` and you also know the output, which is `Min(loss function)`. What you don't know is the input parameters to the model (eg. y=**M**x+**C**). Therefore, a mathematical modelling problem is converted into an optimization approach, which we know very well how to solve.